# jQuery $(this) referencing to HTML document instead of element

Tags: jquery, this

I'm trying to read the rel value of an element.

```
$('.input-default').ready(function()
{
    $('.input-default').inputDefault($(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

But the problem is that $(this) somehow references to the entire HTML document. Why? And how do I fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't trigger it in the `.ready()` event *of the particular element*. I think the context at that time might be window. Just refer to the input directly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var rel =  $('.input-default:first').attr('rel'); //added :first to make sure you only get the rel of the first
});
```

**EDIT**

After reading your comments and doing some searching, I realized you're using the [input default](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/input-default) plugin.

Looking at its documentation, you can do the following to get what you want

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.input.input-default').inputDefault({defaultAttr: 'rel'});
});
```

I'm not sure whether the plugin can be called the way you do in your code, but if you're sure that method works and you want to set the value manually you can do the following.

To iterate through a collection of DOM elements, you can use the `.each()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.input-default').each(function(){
        $(this).inputDefault($(this).attr('rel'));
   });
});
```

Comment: It needs to be generally applicable so I can just give form elements a class input-default and the rel what needs to be the default value of the input field.

Comment: Well, a class can be applied to multiple elements, so call a `.val()` or getting a value won't make sense because you have many instances. If you remove the `:first` filter, you'll get a collection

Comment: =1, your answer is quite a lot better, and more concise, than mine (was) :)

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying John. Why would I call a val()? And why would I want a collection? If input fields are empty, they need to have something like 'Enter your username here', that's what the function is for.

Comment: @Thomas you're working on a class so you will get a collection. Anyway, you might want to mention you're using the `inputdefault` plugin in your question. I've updated my answer and listed your choices

Comment: Although I wasn't using that plugin (I wrote one myself) you fixed it with pointing me to the each function! Thanks John!